# Why does Datagrip use lots of CPU when merely waiting on a long-running query? Can I fix this?

Tags: datagrip

I have found repeatedly over at least the past two years that whenever I have a long-running query, Datagrip's CPU usage goes up and stays up the whole time - even if I am doing absolutely nothing at all. Its like it takes energy just to sit there and wait.

Is this normal?
Is this perhaps related to a jdbc setting? Or what could I possibly do to resolve it?

Context:

- OSX 11.6
- DG 2022.1.1
- Example DB connection: Postgres via JDBC

Comment: If CPU usage is higher than expected, you can capture CPU and share the snapshot via https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE See more in [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems#CPU_Snapshot_2019_2)

Comment: If it hangs (no response at all), you can analyze the threadDumps folder inside [DataGrip logs folder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory). Or share it to analyze via [YouTrack new ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE)

Comment: In general, DataGrip could parse the query and its results to reflect changes in the local representation of your database. So, instead of just waiting, it could consume some CPU for background processes. But high CPU usage seems unusual, so we will be thankful if you share logs and CPU snapshot with YouTrack.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov I finally got a good sample and have uploaded it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16870/Datagrip-2022.1.1-frequently-uses-a-LOT-of-CPU

Comment: Thank you very much! We found some useful clues here. Passed to developer to see how we could fix that.